javax.mail.MessagingException: Can't send command to SMTP host; SSLHandshakeException: No appropriate protocol
We have a Legacy Web Application which was built on Java 1.7, mail1.4.jar and deployed in tomcat 7.
While triggering a mail with attachement to SMPT (nowdays everything move to Microsoft cloud), we are getting below error.
javax.mail.MessagingException: Can't send command to SMTP host;
nested exception is:
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: No appropriate protocol (protocol is disabled or cipher suites are inappropriate)
at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.sendCommand(SMTPTransport.java:1420)
at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.sendCommand(SMTPTransport.java:1408)
at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.ehlo(SMTPTransport.java:847)
at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:384)
at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:297)
Getting all details from property file and setting to properties object i.e., SMPT.HOST: office365 , SMPT.PORT :  587, SMPT.AUTH=true and so on. PFB details.
Code Snippet :
  final String username = ConfReader.getPropertyValue("mail.username");
  final String passwd = ConfReader.getPropertyValue("mail.password");
  from = ConfReader.getPropertyValue("mail.from");
  String port = ConfReader.getPropertyValue("mail.port"); 
  
  Properties props = new Properties();
  props.put("mail.smtp.host", ConfReader.getPropertyValue("mail.smtp.host"));
  props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
  props.put("mail.smtp.port", port);
  props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
  props.put("mail.debug", "true");

  Session session = Session.getInstance(props, new Authenticator() {
      @Override
      protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
          LogWriter.logErrorMessage("username :: "
                  + username + "passwd ::"+passwd);
          return new PasswordAuthentication(username, passwd);
      }
  });
  
    Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
  try
  {
    
     message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));

     final InternetAddress[] toAddress =
        InternetAddress.parse(toEmails);

     final InternetAddress[] ccAddress =
        InternetAddress.parse(ccEmails);
     
     message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, toAddress);
     message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.CC, ccAddress);
     message.setSubject(subject);
    
     /*
      * Multipart to create the mail content.
      */
     final Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();
     /*
      * html body part to set in multipart
      */
    
     final MimeBodyPart htmlBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
     htmlBodyPart.setContent(htmlBody, "text/html");
     multipart.addBodyPart(htmlBodyPart);

     /*
      * source to read attachment content
      */
     DataSource source =
        new ByteArrayDataSource(bytes, "application/excel");
     /*
      * MimeBodyPart to hold the attachment content.
      */
     MimeBodyPart attachmentBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
     DataHandler handler = new DataHandler(source);
     attachmentBodyPart.setHeader("Content-Disposition",
        "attachment;filename=" + attachmentName);
     attachmentBodyPart.setDataHandler(handler);
     attachmentBodyPart.setFileName(attachmentName);
     multipart.addBodyPart(attachmentBodyPart);

     message.setContent(multipart);
     /*
      * following line to send email, if it fails, corresponding catch
      * block executes, which is logged to let know user if any error
      */
    
     Transport.send(message);
    
  }
  catch (AddressException e)
  {
     /*
      * email sending failed, logging the information
      */
    
     LogWriter
        .logErrorMessage("Address Exception : " + e.getMessage());
    
  }
  catch (MessagingException e)
  {
     /*
      * email sending failed, logging the information
      */
    
     LogWriter.logErrorMessage("Messaging Exception : "
        + e.getMessage());
    
 
  }

We have tried below options

We have updated the Mail.14.7.jar

added below properties in code
props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
props.put("mail.debug", "true");

removed the "jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms" security property in the java.security file installed jre folder of deployed server.

Changed the port :25 and make "mail.smtp.starttls.enable"=true.

added below properties in code
props.put("mail.smtp.ssl.protocols", "TLSv1.2");
props.put("mail.smtps.ssl.protocols", "TLSv1.2");


But Still we are facing same issue.
Could you please help us in provide any other solution which will resolve this issue.
Thanks in advance.

Have you tried with a current version of Java? Java 1.7 has been end of life since 2015. Probably it doesn't support current cipher suites. Also using such an old unsupported version is a big security risk.

This application was working perfectly two months back, now it is not working. We did not change any java version or any mail jar version .
As you mentioned , if it is not supporting cipher suite. With any configuration setting can we make it work ?
Currently, we can't upgrade the java version because we got lots of compilation error since application uses old classes and package which are not supported in latest java.

Providers regularly update the security of their systems and may remove support for old protocols and ciphersuites that are considered insecure. Usually it is incumbent on the client to keep up to date. In this case the question doesn't contain enough details to understand what is the specific issue. My recommendation is to enable more SSL logging in Java and test with newer versions of Java, Tomcat and any needed libraries.

Thank you so much.  We have followed steps shared by Conor O'Neill in the below comment. Now it is working.

I had a similar problem in the past. As others have said, this may be subtly dependent on all sorts of things.
The changes which I made at the time, and which worked for me, were to set the mail.smtps.ssl.protocols property to TLSv1.2 (as you've already done), but I also had to modify the javax.mail library version: 
old version javax.mail:mail:1.4 
new version: com.sun.mail:javax.mail:1.6.2
[Yes, theoretically that is sub-optimal because you're now using a specific implementation version, instead of the generic API. But, pragmatically, in circumstances like mine and yours that might be necessary.]
I know that the javax.mail API is now deprecated and replaced with a newer library, but you would almost definitely need other source code changes if moving to the replacement jakarta.mail library.

We followed the same and its working fine now. Thank you for ,your help.
